# KGDB and gdb over serial cable. cannot set breakpoints

Tags: gdb, kernel, kgdb

Two Virtual machines (let's call them development and test) Ubuntu 17.10.
I' ve installed on both kernel 4.15 with the following settings:

```
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_KGDB=y                                                                                               
CONFIG_KGDB=y
CONFIG_KGDB_SERIAL_CONSOLE=y
```

On both machines in /boot directories I have these new files:

```
$ ll /boot/*4.15*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    213741 gen 30 21:36 /boot/config-4.15.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 527443588 gen 30 21:37 /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3956360 gen 30 21:36 /boot/System.map-4.15.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7989008 gen 30 21:36 /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0
```

On the test machine, I've modified grub.cfg this way:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0 root=UUID=2f89c974-19ab-4b5f-96cc871c8aded5b ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff kgdbwait kgdboc=ttyS0,115200
```

I boot test machine, and it stops entering kdb

[image]

I boot development machine and run gdb (version 8.0.1)

```
# gdb /usr/src/linux-4.15/vmlinux
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0.1
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show 
copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /usr/src/linux-4.15/vmlinux...done.
(gdb) target remote /dev/ttyS0
Remote debugging using /dev/ttyS0
0xffffffffb9f4ae04 in ?? ()
(gdb) continue 
Continuing.
```

On "test"

```
# echo g > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

As expected I get s SIGTRAP on development.
Finally, when I should start enjoying setting breakpoint, the disaster happens

```
Thread 62 received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
[Switching to Thread 1698]
0xffffffffb9f4ae04 in ?? ()
(gdb) break oom_kill_process
Breakpoint 1 at 0xffffffff811cc0e0: file mm/oom_kill.c, line 837.
(gdb) continue 
Continuing.
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffff811cc0e0

Command aborted.
(gdb)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add `rodata=off nokaslr` to the kernel command line. This should resolve this problem.